# binary sed replacement

Tags: perl, binary, sed, hex, replace

I was attempting to do a `sed` replacement in a binary file however I am beginning to believe that is not possible.  Essentially what I wanted to do was similar to the following:

```
sed -bi "s/\(\xFF\xD8[[:xdigit:]]\{1,\}\xFF\xD9\)/\1/" file.jpg
```

The logic I wish to achieve is: scan through a binary file until the hex code `FFD8`, continue reading until `FFD9`, and only save what was between them (discards the junk before and after, but include `FFD8` and `FFD9` as the saved part of the file)

Is there a good way to do this?  Even if not using `sed`?

**EDIT:**  I just was playing around and found the cleanest way to do it IMO.  I am aware that this grep statement will act greedy.

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"' dirty.jpg | grep -o "ffd8.*ffd9" | xxd -r -p > clean.jpg
```

Comment: Always beware of false matches when grepping for patterns in what's essentially random data, such as a compressed binary stream!

Comment: @snoopy - (1) is there a better solution? (2) if not, what needs to be done to ameliorate this? Stop searching once some "end of metadata" is reached?

Comment: Depends exactly what you're doing but the CPAN module Image::EXIF lets you extract and change metadata.  Might be of use here.

Comment: FYI, the purpose of this question was for doing manual file carving in a RAID 5 scenario.  When grabbing stripes and chunks you will get data before and after the jpg (or any other file).  This was meant to clean it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[bbe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bbe-/) is a "sed for binary files", and should work more efficiently for large binary files than hexdumping/reconstructing.

An example of its use:

```
$ bbe -e 's/original/replaced/' infile > outfile
```

Further information on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe).

Comment: When I use it on a block device by redirecting it back *(through `-o` option)* into the same device, it seems it modifies more text than the text I wanted to modify. LVM can't even recognize the device as part of a pool after the edit.

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but,

```
xxd infile | sed 's/xxxx xxxx/yyyy yyyy/' | xxd -r > outfile
```

is probably the simplest and most reliable solution. Similar to the edit in the OP.

Comment: Also, using `xxd -g 1 infile` adds a space around every byte, which can make it easier to replace a specific single-byte value.

Comment: Won't this fail if `xxxx xxxx` spans a linebreak?

Comment: I just tried this, the outfile is written, nothing is replaced though?

Comment: Wrong. Doesn't handle line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

sed might be able to do it, but it could be tricky.  Here's a Python script that does the same thing (note that it edits the file in-place, which is what I assume you want to do based on your sed script):

```
import re

f = open('file.jpeg', 'rb+')
data = f.read()
match = re.search('(\xff\xd8[0-9A-fa-f]+)\xff\xd9', data)
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(result)
    f.truncate()
else:
    print 'No match'
f.close()
```

Comment: please kindly how the phrase `(\xff\xd8[0-9A-fa-f]+)\xff\xd9` would change if i want to replace C:\path/sub by /path/sub ? Thank you in advance for possible answer.

Comment: Hey @16851556, your question intrigues me. Challenge accepted.
I believe it becomes `\x43\x3a\x5c([xX]?[0-9a-fA-F]*)`. But `re.search(..., data)` will not do substitution. ;)

Comment: Rather than `\x43\x3a\x5c([xX]?[0-9a-fA-F]*)` I think it should be `\x43\x3a(\x5c([xX]?[0-9a-fA-F]*))+`. Everyone's circumstances are different, but if your employer is asking you to do this, they're completely nuts, and unless you're making crazy money, you must flee from the workplace.

Answer (score 3):

`Is there a good way to do this`

yes of course, use an image editing tool such as those from ImageMagick (search the net for linux jpeg , exif editor etc) that knows how to edit jpg metadata. I am sure you can find one tool that suits you. Don't try to do this the hard way. :)

Comment: agree, this is essentially random binary data so you've got a 1 / (2 ** 16) of getting a false positive when searching for any 2 byte sequence. That's about once every 65K of data.

Comment: exiftool (http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-ExifTool/exiftool) is the killer application for media metadata.

Comment: Just copying my above comment down here:

FYI, the purpose of this question was for doing manual file carving in a RAID 5 scenario. When grabbing stripes and chunks you will get data before and after the jpg (or any other file). This was meant to clean it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, this Perl might work (not tested, *caveat emptor*)... if Python is not installed :)

```
open(FILE, "file.jpg") || die "no open $!\n";
while (read(FILE, $buff, 8 * 2**10)) {
    $content .= $buff;
}
@matches = ($content =~ /(\xFF\xD8[:xdigit:]+?\xFF\xD9)/g;
print STDOUT join("", @matches);
```

You need to add `binmode(FILE); binmode(STDOUT);` on DOS or VMS after the `open()` call - not needed on Unix.

Comment: sorry DVK - that was me. I've been bitten by bugs myself when trying to grep for short patterns in binary data. Just think there's a good chance of this mismatching, either on one or other of the anchors or completely picking up a random 'phantom pattern'. I just think that Sooner or later the OP is likely to end up with the odd scrambled jpeg and wonder why! Also downvoted others for the same reason.

Comment: If you're saying that OP has an XY problem, please present a better solution than a regex before downloading regex solutions as "bad". If this answer has a bug, please point it out. If there's a specific pattern where regexp approach would fail, please clarify that as an answer (again XY)

Comment: Also, please note that this solution does NOT change the jpg file. Merely outputs found strings (which I'm guessing might be metadata) to standard out for later redirect/consumption

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed -i "s/$(python -c "print('\x1f', end='')")/;/g" file
```