# how to replace parameter from a saved xgboost model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, xgboost

This is my environment and parameter of xgboost when I saved a xgboost model.

**environment**

- xgboost version 0.90

**parameter**

- objective: gpu:binary:logistic

I want to load a saved xgboost model in **version 1.0.0**. However, this error massage is occurred.

```
XGBoostError: [12:51:46] C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\xgboost-win64_release_1.0.0\src\objective\objective.cc:26: Unknown objective function: `gpu:binary:logistic`
```

This is because `gpu:binary:logistic` is now deprecated. When I loaded my model in version 0.90, this warnings is occurred.

```
[13:45:14] WARNING: C:/Jenkins/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_0.90/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:170: gpu:binary:logistic is now deprecated, use binary:logistic instead.
```

I tried to apply `set_params` for replacing `gpu:binary:logistic` to `binary:logistic` and saved a model. **But, it didn't work.**

```py
import xgboost as xgb

model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.load_model('xgb.model')

params = {'objective':'binary:logistic'}
model.set_params(**params)
```

I tried to replace 'gpu:binary:logistic' to 'binary:'logistic' from a saved model file, but OSError was occurred.

```py
temp = open('test.model','rb')
lines = temp.readlines()
lines[0] = lines[0].replace(b'gpu:',b'')

new_model = open('test_replace.model','wb')

for line in lines:
    new_model.write(line)
new_model.close()
```

And OSError was appeared when I loaded model.

```py
model = xgb.XGBClassifier()
model.load_model('test_replace.model')
```

```
OSError: [WinError -529697949] Windows Error 0xe06d7363
```

This is a saved xgboost model. This file was saved as `model` format

b'\x00\x00\x00\x80\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00gpu:binary:logistic\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00gbtree\xfb\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00

I can't re-train my model. For this reason, I have to fix this problem from a saved model.

**How to fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the objective function is stored as a string in the model file. Simply perform a binary-aware replacement `gpu:binary:logistic` -> `binary:logistic` on your model file!

Should be doable using command-line tools, see for example this SO thread: [binary sed replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604964/binary-sed-replacement)

Upon a successful replacement, the size of the model file should shrink by 4 bytes (the length of the `gpu:` prefix).

Comment: As your answer, I opened my model in python and replaced `gpu:' to ''. However, OSError was occurred.

Comment: OK, my bad. The string value is stored as `<int:string length in bytes><byte[]:string content>`. In addition to changing the string value, you'd need to update the leading string length indicator field as well (subtract 4 from the current value).

Comment: Right now you have: `<int:19>gpu:binary:logistic`, but you'd need to have `<int 15>binary:logistic`

Comment: Please note that the length is actually written using the `long64` data type, so it's 8 bytes right before the beginning of the string value.

Comment: A model file was written using `int` data type, But I'm not sure if this file used the `long64` data type. How can I figure out if `long64` data type is used?

Comment: TLDR: look up the eight byte sequence right before the `gpu:binary:logistic` byte sequence part starts in the model file. There should be seven `0`-value bytes and a single `19`-value byte (`0x13` in hexadecimal). Change this byte to `15`-value byte (`0xf`). Does it work then?

Comment: I see you've edited your question so that it includes the head of the model file. This is the byte sequence `\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00gpu:binary:logistic`; replace it with `\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00binary:logistic` and you should be good to go!

Comment: Great! According to SO guidelines, you should mark this answer (and its comments) as "accepted" to show to others that you problem has been solved.